# MS Access combobox rowsource target database

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc

I have an old access database which queries a central SQL Server that I am trying to work with.

At the moment we only have one copy of this which points at the live database.

I have made a copy of the access database and a copy of the sql database to try and create a test environment. While I have managed to nail all of the hard coded connection details on each form, I am unable to find the place where the combo boxes get ther data. we have code like this in the background:

```
cmbSeries.RowSourceType = "Table/View/StoredProc"
cmbSeries.RowSource = "exec p_DispBoardSeries @Year='" & cmbYear2 & _
    "', @Board='" & cmbBoard & "'"
cmbSeries.Requery
```

Can anytone tell me where the connection is set? I am stumped! Its still querying the live database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nailed it!

To find this setting:

1. Right click on the **quick access toolbar** (it should be to the right
   of the office button and have the little save disk icon and other bits in there)
2. Click **"Customise Quick Access Toolbar..."**
3. Change the **"Choose commands from"** drop down to **"All"**
4. Find the command simply called **"Connection"** (it looks like a blue rectangle with a little green loop to a server symbol)
5. Click **"Add"** to add it to the toolbar
6. Click **"OK"**

Now you will see this icon appear in your Quick Access Toolbar. Click it and you can change the connection for the whole access database.

If anyone out there knows where this option actually exists in the menu structure, say so in the comments! I'll update this answer.